# Want to add more drops to my mining function

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a working button that adds exp to my total exp then has a chance to give you 1 bronze on click. I want when my mininglv >=10 for silver to be added to that.

I've tried making another if  statement (probably formatted it wrong) that is if (mininglv >=10 && mininglv < 20) then repeating the lines for bronze and mining exp then adding a silver random thing. I cant figure out how to add silver to the chance to get from the click of the button and give it a chance of 0.25.

This is my javaScript code:

```
var Bronzechance = 0.5
var Silverchance = 0.25

function Miningaction() {
    if (MiningCexp < NextMaxMiningExp && Mininglv >= 1) {
        MiningCexp = MiningCexp + 1;
        if (Math.random() < Bronzechance)
        Bronze = Bronze + 1
    document.getElementById("Bronze").innerHTML = Bronze;
    document.getElementById("MiningCexp").innerHTML = MiningCexp;
} 
if(Mininglv >=10 && Mininglv <20){
    MiningCexp = MiningCexp + 1;
    if (Math.random() < Silverchance){
        Silver = Silver + 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("Bronze").innerHTML = Bronze;
    document.getElementById("Silver").innerHTML = Silver;
    document.getElementById("MiningCexp").innerHTML = MiningCexp;

} else {
    Mininglv = Mininglv + 1
    MiningCexp = 0
    Mining = Mining + 1
    NextMaxMiningExp = NextMaxMiningExp * 1.5;
    document.getElementById('MiningMexp').innerHTML = NextMaxMiningExp;
    document.getElementById('Mininglv').innerHTML = Mininglv;
    document.getElementById('MiningCexp').innerHTML = MiningCexp;
    document.getElementById('Mining').innerHTML = Mining;
}
```

}

Html code :

```
 Bronze: <span id="Bronze">0</span>
 <br />
 Silver: <span id="Bronze">0</span>

<button onclick="Miningaction()"><img src="cave.png" alt="cave" 
height="45" width="45"> </button>
```

I expect when button clicked when mining level is 10 or higher but not higher then 20 to have a chance to give you silver. But the actual output I can't get silver to drop.

Comment: I don't know how to format the code to get it to work though. I will try some more stuff. I wanted to add gold and diamond later on to and a way to increase drop chance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var Bronzechance = 0.5;
var Silverchance = 0.25;
var Bronze = 0;
var Silver = 0;

function Miningaction() {
    MiningCexp = MiningCexp + 1;
    if (Mininglv >= 1) {
        if (Math.random() < Bronzechance)
            Bronze = Bronze + 1;
        document.getElementById("Bronze").innerHTML = Bronze;
        document.getElementById("MiningCexp").innerHTML = MiningCexp;

    }

    if(Mininglv >=10 && Mininglv < 20){
        if (Math.random() < Silverchance){
            Silver = Silver + 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("Silver").innerHTML = Silver;
        document.getElementById("MiningCexp").innerHTML = MiningCexp;

    if(MiningCexp >= NextMaxMiningExp)
        Mininglv = Mininglv + 1;
        MiningCexp = 0;
        Mining = Mining + 1;
        NextMaxMiningExp = NextMaxMiningExp * 1.5;
        document.getElementById('MiningMexp').innerHTML = NextMaxMiningExp;
        document.getElementById('Mininglv').innerHTML = Mininglv;
        document.getElementById('MiningCexp').innerHTML = MiningCexp;
        document.getElementById('Mining').innerHTML = Mining;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks will this let me eventually add a way to up the drop chances of each item through upgrades?

Comment: If you get an upgrade, you can just increase the SilverChance. If you purchase an item that doubles mining rate you could just do `SilverChance = SilverChance*2`

Comment: so i set Minininglv = 10 to test it but then the button doesnt work http://prntscr.com/nuqr32

Comment: well with brackets it marks like 50 things wrong that aren't wrong like document.getele. I will try to find a error

Comment: I fixed the Mininglv not being capalized. did you fix anything other then that

Comment: When you put your HTML code, you put  `Silver: <span id="Bronze">0</span>`, maybe the error is you trying to set `document.getElementById("Silver").innerHTML = Silver;` when the element with the id `silver` doesn't actually exist?

Comment: wow i didn't even notice that thanks. i fixed that but still same issue.

Comment: Only things i can see why the code i provided wouldn't work was just capitalisation mistakes (Another one at `Math.random() < SilverChance`)(which i've fixed now). Other than that i can't see why it wouldn't be working

Comment: that did the trick but now it stopped bronze from dropping just silver is dropping

Comment: im afraid math.random will be tied to the same value and that bronze will only drop when silver drops. ill try some stuff.

Comment: I have fixed it, the reason was you wanted bronze to drop only up to 10, not up to 20, so it was never dropping. i also added a few changes

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nuqy96  yea this is wrong. made it so bronze only drops when silver does

Comment: You should *not* do the code as you have done, that means that they must *both* be dropping *at the same time*, making the chance `0.5*0.25`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nuqzsu  the max exp isnt updateing correctly. its also not adding 1 to exp but the values seam to be going up nicely. I will try useing ctrl z to go back and seen if i can combine th formats.

Comment: I will update my code. I have it all working but now im getting 2 mining exp per click

Comment: I fixed it, that was because you changed what the outcome of the question was

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nur2th it works thank you so much. idk if you can see my previous questions but i'm pretty far into this game and I cannot for the life of me get setintervals to work. http://prntscr.com/nur4ic this makes it go off at the start of the program but I want the autoclick to go off after buying a upgrade. if you can help me with my manaregen questions id appreciate it.